# Giphy Gifs having strange behaviour on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, gif, animated-gif, giphy

I was trying to make use of facebook's new ability to show actual gifs in autoplay to make a small looping advertising for a facebook page.

I tested out the feature initially using some Giphy gifs and found it worked fine, receiving the visual message that facebook was loading the gif and it actually working on autoplay and looped forever on a user facebook "wall".

The thing is, with some more testing I found out there are 2 different behaviours for giphy gifs when you post its link:

1 - It behaves perfectly and works as expected and as an actual GIF.

2 - It weirdly adopts a sort of "video form" that doesn't auto-play and makes use of flash to loop the gif...

I tried to guess through some testing why that happened and thought I found a pattern regarding the actual number of frames and the resolution but still I can't get my uploaded gif to work fine.

http://gph.is/1PPYUPn

However this one that has bigger resolution and a larger number of frames behaves perfectly.

http://gph.is/1OuQv3a

Any fellow developer or someone from Giphy that is available to help me out?

UPDATE: I also noticed that the debug info from facebook for both links is completely different! Check it on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

1. upload your animation (mov or gif) on [giphy.com](http://giphy.com/)
2. copy link that looks like this: http://giphy.com/gifs/str4ng35tr1nG
3. open https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
4. paste link and click „Debug”
5. your animation will show as a static link to *media.giphy.com/…*
6. after 30 sec, click „Scrape Again”
7. if this not help, try again until (GIF) symbol will appear on your animation. Now you know that you can paste link in post and animation will work as it should.